# Spring Integration flow picked up file keeps appearing in the local folder

Tags: spring-integration

I have a document server applications. Separate flows are there for files picked up from the ftp folder and put in the local directory. The second flow is for files getting picked up and put in the FTP location. I have added a AcceptOnceFileListFilter for both as well as a custom pattern matcher which is same in both cases (something~something). The local directory as well as the ftp folder are different for this.

I need to let the source files exist even after being picked up, hence I have removed the deletesourcefiles attribute.

With this I am facing a problem of files repeatedly coming to the filter and getting processed. How can this happen with the AcceptOnceFileListFilter in place? I would anyway need to avoid the same files repeatedly getting processed.

This is my entire configuration.

```
          <bean id="fileNameGenerator" class="com.polling.util.FileNameGenerator"/>   
    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${paths.root}" channel="abc" filter="compositeFilter" prevent-duplicates="true" >
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="500" error-channel="errorChannel" />

    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorLogger" method="logError"/>
    <bean id="errorLogger" class="com.polling.util.ErrorLogger" />
    <int:channel id="abc"/>
    <bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Ensures that the file is whole before processing it -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" />
                <bean class="com.polling.util.CustomFileFilter"/>
                <!-- Ensures files are picked up only once from the directory -->

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean> 

    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="abc" id="filesOut"
        directory-expression="@outPathBean.getPath()"
        delete-source-files="true" filename-generator="fileNameGenerator" temporary-file-suffix=".writinginprog">
        <int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
          </bean>
    </int-file:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>
   <bean id="ftpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${ftp.ip}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
<int:channel id="ftpChannel1"/> 
 <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound1"
    channel="ftpChannel1"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="file:${paths.downloadroot}"
    delete-remote-files="true"
    temporary-file-suffix=".write"
    remote-directory="."
    preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true" 
    local-filter="compositeFilterLocal" 
    >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
  <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound1"
    channel="ftpChannel1"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="${file.ftpdownloadfolder}" 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
     temporary-file-suffix=".write">
    <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
          </bean>
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>



   <int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>
<!--filter="compositeFilterRemote"   filename-pattern="*~*"   filename-pattern="*~*"-->
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="file:${paths.root}"
   filter="compositeFilterRemote"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    remote-directory="${file.ftpfolder}"

    delete-remote-files="true"
     preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="errorChannel"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="${file.ftpfolder}" 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
     temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
    <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
          </bean>
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
  </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
<bean id="compositeFilterLocal" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Ensures that the file is whole before processing it -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />
                <bean class="com.polling.util.CustomFileFilterLocal"/>
                <!-- Ensures files are picked up only once from the directory -->

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="compositeFilterRemote" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Ensures that the file is whole before processing it -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />
                <bean class="com.polling.util.CustomFileFilterRemote"/>
                <!-- Ensures files are picked up only once from the directory -->

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

1. ftpChannel picks file from ftp folder and puts in local directory
   abc picks the file from there and puts the renamed file to a dynamically generated folder.
2. ftpchannel1 picks file on another local directory and puts it on the remote folder.

EDIT:

Changed the configuration from fixed-rate to fixed-delay. I don't remember why I had changed it to fixed-rate last month! Anyway, the large file problem is resolved as of now. The acceptoncefilter still does not do its job though. The does not delete the file from the local directory after the file inbound adapter picks it up.

There is another issue. There are two ftp channels with different remote folders and different local folders. I want each to be unidirectional. Means one should pick up files from the remote dir and put it on the local one and the other should be vice-versa. Because of the above problem the file is still in the local dir and gets picked up by the other flow and put back on the remote directory! Cannot null one of the dir either. Please guide me in this as it is essential to not delete the files on the remote dir.

Comment: Doesn't `AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` implementation help you?

Comment: implementation? I have configured it in xml as shown above. I first noticed the issue when though the delete source files attribute was true , if the file size is > 30 mb the local folder file gets picked up by the file inbound adapter once successfully and then keeps getting picked up always!!

Comment: No, I mean `PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` instead of `in-memory` `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`

Comment: Please explain the implementation tag

Comment: `AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` is **abstract**. So to use that stuff you should select the specific implementation for your case: `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`, `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` etc..

Comment: got a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.<init>() exception when i changed the tag  <bean class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter" />

Comment: That's true. See the ctor of that class. You should inject `ConcurrentMetadataStore` and provide the `prefix`. Can be empty string.

Comment: I did not understand completely. Are you saying that if the file is too large the AcceptOnceFileListFilter does not work? Also the same thing is happening if the deletesourcefiles attribute is false. If that is the solution please explain with more details. Thanks

Comment: How does it work, if you change the order of filter for those `CompositeFileListFilter` beans? I mean `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` first in the `<list>` definition and only after that your `CustomFileFilter`

Comment: No change. Local file does not go or keeps reappearing. Even after deletesourcefiles is true, the file gets deleted from the remote directory

Comment: Well. Would be better, if you minimize your config and wrap it to the test-case to reproduce.

Comment: edited the q. the process works if the file is small and deletesourcefiles is true

Comment: Sorry, your config is still complex. Try to localize an issue around the concrete component to figure out it and try to come up with test-case to investigate. Yes, I understand that you advocate for big file, but it isn't still clear to me which is blame: file or ftp adapter.

Comment: Try to use `fixed-delay`. It is exactly the option to schedule a new poll task only after the finish of previous one. Right now yes: if you file is enough big a new task can be started during the invocation of another one. It isn't related to the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` though, unless your logic generates some ambiguity file names.